# Running ng test throws many errors and gets failed

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, typescript2.0

```
angular-cli v1.0.0 beta.21
typescript version 2.0.10
```

Currently, I'm using these two versions of typescript and angular-cli. 
When I  run `ng test` I'm getting these errors -

1. Error: No provider for Http!
   [image]
2. Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
   [image]
3. app-navbar is not a known element
   [image]

Here is source code of app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule, JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from './results/results.component';
import {Routes, RouterModule, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {SearchService} from './search.service';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { AdvancedsearchComponent } from './advancedsearch/advancedsearch.component';
import {StoreDevtoolsModule} from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {reducer} from './reducers/index';
import { SearchBarComponent } from './search-bar/search-bar.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'search', component: ResultsComponent},
{path: '', component: IndexComponent},
{path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'},
];
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
NavbarComponent,
IndexComponent,
ResultsComponent,
NotFoundComponent,
AdvancedsearchComponent,
SearchBarComponent
],
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
CommonModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
JsonpModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
StoreModule.provideStore(reducer),
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentOnlyWithExtension(),
],
providers: [SearchService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

search.service.spec.ts

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SearchService } from './search.service';

describe('SearchService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [SearchService]
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([SearchService], (service: SearchService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

search.component.spec.ts

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { SearchBarComponent } from './search-bar.component';

describe('SearchBarComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchBarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchBarComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SearchBarComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchBarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

results.component.spec.ts

```
 /* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { ResultsComponent } from './results.component';

describe('ResultsComponent', () => {
  let component: ResultsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ResultsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ResultsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ResultsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

results.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Start ignoring BootLintBear -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1">
                <!-- Stop ignoring BootLintBear -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <div class="btn-group" id="search-options">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [class.active_view]="Display('all')" (click)="docClick()">
                        All
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [class.active_view]="Display('images')" (click)="imageClick()">Images</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [class.active_view]="Display('videos')" (click)="videoClick()">Videos</button>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="tools" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search-tools">
                            Tools <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse" id="search-tools">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="filterByContext()" type="button"> Context Ranking</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="filterByDate()" type="button"> Sort by Date</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="advancedsearch()" type="button"> Advanced Search</button>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="container-fluid" id="progress-bar">
                    {{message}}
                </div>
                <div class="text-result" *ngIf="Display('all')">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of items$|async" class="result">
                        <div class="title">
                            <a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                            <p>{{item.link}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {{item.pubDate|date:'fullDate'}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-result" *ngIf="Display('images')">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of items$|async">
                        <img class="res-img" src="{{item.link}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="video-result" *ngIf="Display('videos')">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="result">
                        <div class="title">
                            <a href="{{item.path}}">{{item.title}}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="link">
                            <p>{{item.link}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="pagination-property">
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                        <ul class="pagination" id="pag-bar">
                            <li class="page-item"><span class="page-link" href="#" (click)="decPresentPage()">Previous</span></li>
                            <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let num of getNumber(maxPage)"><span class="page-link"
                                                                             *ngIf="presentPage>=4 && num<=noOfPages"
                                                                             [class.active_page]="getStyle(presentPage-3+num)"
                                                                             (click)="getPresentPage(presentPage-3+num)"
                                                                             href="#">{{presentPage-3+num}}</span>
                                <span class="page-link" *ngIf="presentPage<4 && num<=noOfPages" [class.active_page]="getStyle(num)"
                  (click)="getPresentPage(num)" href="#">{{num+1}}</span></li>
                            <li class="page-item"><span class="page-link" (click)="incPresentPage()">Next</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <app-advancedsearch></app-advancedsearch>
    </div>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "susper",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^1.2.5",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.1.6",
    "reselect": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

I needed help in this quickly, I have googled a lot about it. Did changes according to the sources, but still I'm getting these errors. Now I'm only left with this option to post it here on Stack-overflow. These errors only occurs when I run `ng test`. Also, I have gone through issues related to this on Stack overflow and updated my typescript version and angular-cli version. I have written the versions in starting. Thank you for giving time to this question :)

Comment: Looks like *HttpModule* correct but try after removing comma after *JsonpModule*. For 2nd issue, Can you provide HTML code, Where you are getting this error.

Comment: @NNR I have provided the HTML code where the elements like <app navbar>, <app search-bar>, <app advancedsearch> is used. I have added also another issue, `app navbar is not a known element` . Above I have added point no. 3 which includes the screenshot of the following. I have removed comma after `JsonpModule`.

Comment: You're not posting the code of the tests that fail. So it's hard to know why they fail and what you should change.

Comment: @JBNizet I have posted the code of tests.

Comment: Each of your tests creates a test module containing the tested component/service only. But the component/service under test relies on the http module to be imported by the module, as well as the forms module, etc. So you need to change the test module definition, import all the required modules, add the needed components to the declarations, etc. Just like you would need to do it in the application NgModule.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks! All the errors have been solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome and solve all the errors - import all the modules -

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule, JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from './results/results.component';
import {Routes, RouterModule, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {SearchService} from './search.service';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { AdvancedsearchComponent } from './advancedsearch/advancedsearch.component';
import {StoreDevtoolsModule} from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import {StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
import {reducer} from './reducers/index';
import { SearchBarComponent } from './search-bar/search-bar.component';
```

in each `.component.spec.ts`. Doing this, `ng test` will run fine without giving any errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to import HttpClientTestingModule in the spec
   file.
2. You need to import ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule in your spec file.
3. I assume app-navbar is a reusable component that you might have defined in your shared.module, so you would need to import SharedModule in your spec file.

All the above imports should be added in the spec file which is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to import the dependencies using the `imports` key.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  import: [ SomeModule ]
})
```